# Laravel - separate session lifetime for each user

Tags: php, laravel, session, session-timeout

In my PHP Laravel application, each user (`User` model) belongs to an organization (`Organization` model). I need to be able to configure the session lifetime (`session.lifetime` config value) separately for each user based on the organization.

The value is stored in the database -> `organizations` table -> `session_lifetime` column (integer). Organization's admin users are able to change it in the admin page.

I have created a `CustomSessionLifetime` middleware:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    $user = auth()->user();

    if ($user !== null)
    {
        $lifetime = $user->organization->session_lifetime;
        config()->set('session.lifetime', $lifetime);
    }
    
    return $next($request);
}
```

Now I have kind of a circular problem:

**1)** If I set the `CustomSessionLifetime` middleware to run *BEFORE* `StartSession` middleware, like this:

```
/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        //...
        \App\Http\Middleware\CustomSessionLifetime::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        //...
    ],
```

then I am unable to get the user (and thus the organization or the `session_lifetime` attribute value) using `auth()->user()` function because the session is not yet started.

**2)** If I set the `CustomSessionLifetime` middleware to run *AFTER* `StartSession` middleware, like this:

```
/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        //...
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\CustomSessionLifetime::class,
        //...
    ],
```

then I am unable to configure the `session.lifetime` config value because the session is already started and the old value has been used there.

I was kind of surprised that Laravel didn't have a native way to achieve something like this as I think it seems pretty standard to want to customize the session lifetime based on user somehow.

How could I make this work?

Comment: Which laravel version? Also are you using any package like sanctum/fortify or custom for now?

Comment: @DarkKnight Laravel version 8.52.0 using PHP version 7.4.16. I am not using any packages related to session. Session driver is redis.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a pretty decent workaround for this, by using two custom middlewares and a cookie.

`BeforeStartSession.php` middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class BeforeStartSession
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $cookieName = 'session_lifetime_cookie';
        $value = $request->cookie($cookieName, 0);
        $lifetime = (int) $value;

        if ($lifetime !== 0)
        {
            config()->set('session.lifetime', $lifetime);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

`AfterStartSession.php` middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie;

class AfterStartSession
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = auth()->user();

        $cookieName = 'session_lifetime_cookie';
        $value = $request->cookie($cookieName, 0);
        $oldLifetime = (int) $value;

        if ($user !== null)
        {
            $newLifetime = $user->organization->session_lifetime;

            // Only add the cookie to the response if it doesn't exist
            // or the lifetime value has changed
            if ($oldLifetime === 0 || $oldLifetime !== $newLifetime)
            {
                Cookie::queue(Cookie::forever($cookieName, $newLifetime));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Only forget the cookie if it exists
            if ($oldLifetime !== 0)
            {
                Cookie::queue(Cookie::forget($cookieName));
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

These are added to the `$middlewareGroups` array in the `Kernel.php` file so they are before and after the `StartSession` default middleware:

```
/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        //...
        \App\Http\Middleware\BeforeStartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\AfterStartSession::class,
        //...
    ],
```

I also added the cookie manually in my login controller after succesfully logging the user in so the `BeforeStartSession` middleware picks up the correct value immediately after redirecting the user:

```
// Handle login
Auth::login($user);

$cookieName = 'session_lifetime_cookie';
Cookie::queue(Cookie::forever($cookieName, $user->organization->session_lifetime));
```

The only downside in this is that as cookies are stored client side, users are able to remove them (even if they are re-added after every request), decreasing the security of it. I countered this by having the default lifetime pretty low value.

This of course also adds some extra data to all requests as the Laravel cookie values are encrypted.